# .get() event listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener

I'm having a bit of jquery trouble. For some crazy reason, when I load a div from another page using .get() and clone it, its event listeners all disappear. When I clone a div on the same page, the event listeners stay, so the problem seems to be .get()'s fault.

Here's the code that works (keeps the event listeners):

```
var div = $("#"+referencedPostNumber).clone(true,true).attr("id","inlineQuote"+referencedPostNumber)
$(div).css("border","1px solid grey");
$(div).css("display","table");
$(reference).after(div);
```

And here's the code that doesn't:

```
$.get(reference.href, function(data) {
    var div = $($(data).find('#' + referencedPostNumber)).clone(true,true).attr("id","inlineQuote"+referencedPostNumber)
    $(div).css("border","1px solid grey");
    $(div).css("display","table");  
    $(reference).after(div);
});
```

Comment: Where are the event handlers being bound?

Comment: You can only bind events to elements which exist in the DOM. When they're removed from the DOM, the binding is lost, and needs to be rebound. You can get around all of this if you learn how to use [event delegation](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2010/03/4/event-delegation-with-jquery) (the post is a bit old, but it serves its purpose).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: In some javascript that gets ran when the page loads. Is there anyways to get .get() to run that stuff on the data it fetches?